# Join Matrix Fields To Query Using andWhere

Tags: matrix, craft3

My question is this, **I want to join a matrix table to a query and look for certain values in it**.  I am using this example below.  I have 2 matrix fields partsModels.model and partsModels.parts. I need to make sure that all the criteria is met before looping through any of the data.

`{% set entries = craft.entries.andWhere(['like', 'content.fields_myFieldHandle', 'foo']).all() %}`

that Robin supplied [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26152/craft-query-matrix-blocks-in-twig/26153?noredirect=1#comment34376_26153).

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on Craft's site on how to structure or code such a query.  Has anyone done this before or used the andWhere on Matrix fields?

Comment: Seems like it be easier to just use `search`? It'll ultimately get translated to a `like` on the backend in most cases anyway. `{% set entries = craft.matrixBlocks.search('*foo*').all() %}`

Comment: Thanks Brad.  Since that searches through all instances of foo, it will capture things I don't want in the output.  Plus I have two Matrix fields I need to compare before displaying the results.  Like here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26183/match-matrix-fields-before-looping-through-results