# Match Matrix Fields Before Looping Through Results

Tags: matrix, craft3, forloop

I hope someone has an example or something similar they have done in Craft before.  Her is what I have.

**Structure:**

Section -> **Flight Company**

Matrix Name -> **Plane Details**

Matrix Block: **Plane Model and Part**

Matrix Fields -> **Model, Part** (field type: Category)

I am needing to perform this match example (preferable in crafts.entries query)before looping through the records.

**Example match needed:**

Model = Cessna

Part = Propx45

I need to match both those conditions before looping through the results later on in the page.  I need to make sure all the Flight Company's match that criteria before outputing the Title of the Flight Company.

How best to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to be clear, both `Model` and `Part` are 2 separate Categories fields inside of the Matrix field "Degree Programs"? Is there only one Matrix Block in that field?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had Degree Programs by mistake, it's Plane Details.  But yes, they are both inside one Matrix Block, updated with the correct structure of that Matrix Field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Turns out the original answer only works if you've got an single instance of a Matrix Block on the entry.  If you have multiple, it will search through all of them and return results for any block that has *any* of the relations you're looking for, in spite of the inclusion of `and`.

As of the next [post-3.0.9](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#309---2018-05-22) release, you'll be able to get relational matches from individual Matrix Block instances using a method like so:

```
{% set targetModel = craft.categories.id(5).one() %}
{% set targetPart = craft.categories.id(20).one() %}

{# be sure and set the field ID of the Matrix field you're interested in here %}
{% set entryIds = craft.matrixBlocks.fieldId(55).relatedTo(['and',
        { targetElement: targetModel, field: 'model' },
        { targetElement: targetPart, field: 'part' },
    ])
    .select(['ownerId'])
    .distinct()
    .column()
%}


{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entryIds).all() %}

{# display the results #}
Total: {{ entries|length }}<br>

<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Original Answer**
Assuming the setup in your question, something like this should work:

```
{# These are just two examples, but get the relevant target model and part categories however you want #}

{# resolve to the "Cessna" category #}
{% set targetModel = craft.categories.id(4).one() %}

{# resolve to the "Propx45" category #}
{% set targetPart = craft.categories.id(6).one() %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('flightCompany').relatedTo(['and',
    { targetElement: targetModel, field: 'planeDetails.model' },
    { targetElement: targetPart, field: 'planeDetails.part' },
]).all() %}

{# display the results #}
Total: {{ entries|length }}<br>

<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here's the relevant "relations" part of the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html

Comment: I did all that, made sure it was right and get 0 results.  I get the correct value from targetModel & targetPart but still no results.  Triple check everything.  Back when I started to look for an answer, the one you provided here I tried and got zero then too, so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Also to let you know some of my records have apostrophes in them, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Must be something else affecting it then. If you want to send a database dump over to support@craftcms.com we can test.

Comment: I will do, will be good to have this working eventually.  I’ve been working at this for close to 2 weeks.